# Proper Line of Sight in tile based game

Tags: 2d, grid, line-of-sight

My rendering engine currently takes "xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax" to render a rectangular region of tiles, and will automatically scale based on the size of the panel it is rendering to.

However, I am having an issue rendering based on line of sight. Currently (I know this is inefficient but it is simply the best option as of right now) I use Bresenham's line algorithm. However, that results in
[image: this]

As you can see, the walls invisible. How should I go about updating the algorithm to have it make the walls visible as well?

If I render tiles that end where the raytrace ended, I get
[image: some walls showing]

This implies that a floating point solution would be preferred.

Of note, I will accept suggestions on how to improve the rendering engine if it would make this more possible.

Comment: I think you need to review your question. You're saying the walls are visible, and then you ask how to make the walls visible? Also, perhaps add some circles/text to the image to show us what is what. Right now the question is unclear, and you'll risk it getting closed.

Comment: Whoooops! I guess it shows I was a little tired writing this question. I'll revamp it.

Comment: The usual light of sight for *tiles* tells you which horizontal floor surfaces are visible. You *also* want to show the walls which have a vertical surface visible. The vertical surfaces are edges in the tile map. Bresenham's algorithm only finds the tiles; you can use a different line drawing algorithm (see [my page](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/line-drawing.html#stepping) for example) that finds the edges.

Comment: That results in the same issue. I might be doing something wrong on my side. I implement the function as visibilityCheck( x1, y1, x2, y2 )  and return true if the tile is visible so the engine knows it can render that tile. If you know of a better alternative that your solution will work with please let me know.

Comment: It would be useful if you add your current approach. Like, if you check from the point out to a perimeter or how you're trying to solve it.